# Inject class from bean with property HashMaps of <String, Class>

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, enums

I'm looking to populate a class with two HashMaps of types HashMap via spring injection.  Unfortunately I'm getting the following error when I attempt to build my platform.

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'EnumUtil' defined in class path resource [payment3dsi-spring.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'util:map#4b13c655' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'stateCodes'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'util:map#4b13c655': Error converting typed String value for bean property 'sourceMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [US-IL], target type [class java.lang.String]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.gsk.platform.payment3dsi.cardmanagement.CreditCardManagementServiceStub$StateProvinceCode'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.gsk.platform.payment3dsi.cardmanagement.CreditCardManagementServiceStub$StateProvinceCode]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I'm not sure why there are conversion errors? I should just be setting a key/value pair, no conversion needed.  My bean looks like this:

```
    <bean name="EnumUtil" class="com.gsk.platform.payment3dsi.util.EnumUtil" scope="tenant">
    <property name="stateCodes">
        <util:map map-class="java.util.HashMap" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="com.gsk.platform.payment3dsi.cardmanagement.CreditCardManagementServiceStub.StateProvinceCode">
            <entry key="US-IL" value="StateProvinceCode.Illinois" />
            .
            .
            .....etc
        </util:map>
    </property>
    <property name="countryCodes">
        <util:map map-class="java.util.HashMap" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="com.gsk.platform.payment3dsi.cardmanagement.CreditCardManagementServiceStub.CountryCode">
            <entry key="US" value="CountryCode.UnitedStates" />
            <entry key="CA" value="CountryCode.Canada" />
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My Enum class looks like the following:

```
package com.gsk.platform.payment3dsi.util;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.gsk.platform.payment3dsi.cardmanagement.CreditCardManagementServiceStub.CountryCode;
import com.gsk.platform.payment3dsi.cardmanagement.CreditCardManagementServiceStub.StateProvinceCode;

public class EnumUtil {
    private HashMap<String, StateProvinceCode> stateCodes;
    private HashMap<String, CountryCode> countryCodes;

    private HashMap<String, StateProvinceCode> getStateCodes() {
        return stateCodes;
    }

    private HashMap<String, CountryCode> getCountryCodes() {
        return countryCodes;
    }

    public void setStateCodes(HashMap<String, StateProvinceCode> stateCodes) {
        this.stateCodes = stateCodes;
    }

    public void setCountryCodes(HashMap<String, CountryCode> countryCodes) {
        this.countryCodes = countryCodes;
    }

    public String getRegionCodeForStateCode(StateProvinceCode stateProvinceCode){
        for(Entry<String, StateProvinceCode> entry : stateCodes.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getValue().equals(stateProvinceCode)){
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public StateProvinceCode getStateCodeFromRegionCode(String regionCode){
        return getStateCodes().get(regionCode);
    }

    public String getCountryIsoForCountryCode(CountryCode countryCode){
        for(Entry<String, CountryCode> entry : countryCodes.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getValue().equals(countryCode)){
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public CountryCode getCountryCodeFromCountryIso(String countryCode){
        return getCountryCodes().get(countryCode);
    }
}
```

And I'm attempting to use this class in my code in the following manner:

```
    @Resource(name = "EnumUtil")
    private EnumUtil enumUtil;

    .
    .
    .


    billingAddress.setStateProvinceCode(enumUtil.getStateCodeFromRegionCode(billingAddressData.getRegion().getIsocode()));
billingAddress.setCountryCode(enumUtil.getCountryCodeFromCountryIso(billingAddressData.getCountry().getIsocode()));
```

Any ideas on what the issue is here? I'm just looking to inject these two pre-populated maps into the class and not sure what the conversion error is from.  Thanks!

Comment: Consider switching to Java configs

Comment: Are `StateProvinceCode` and the others enum types?

Comment: They are not unfortunately.  They are public variables, I just need a way to map them to the strings I inherit in the method.

Comment: I'm talking about the types `StateProvinceCode` and `CountryCode`. Are they `class` types or `enum` types? How do you expect Spring to convert `value="CountryCode.UnitedStates"` to a `CountryCode` value?

Comment: They are `class` types.  I thought that spring would resolve it to the type based on the `value-type="com.gsk.platform.payment3dsi.cardmanagement.CreditCardManagementServiceStub.StateProvinceCode"`

Comment: And convert it how? How do you go from the String `"CountryCode.UnitedStates"` to an instance of type `CountryCode`?

Comment: I thought that the `value-type` field would proclaim that `"CountryCode.UnitedStates"` is NOT a string and rather a `com.gsk.platform.payment3dsi.cardmanagement.CreditCardManagementSer​viceStub.StateProvinceCode` type as I stated above.  So it would not expect a String.

Comment: So can I only create mappings of Strings this way? Is it possible to have a type as the value as I've attempted to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try this option. It will be verbose though.

```
<property name="countryCodes">
        <util:map map-class="java.util.HashMap" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="com.gsk.platform.payment3dsi.cardmanagement.CreditCardManagementServiceStub.CountryCode">
            <entry>
                <key>US</key>
                <value>
                    <bean class="com.gsk.platform.payment3dsi.cardmanagement.CreditCardManagementServiceStub.CountryCode">
                        <!-- Instantiate your country here --!>
                    </bean>
                </value>
            </entry>
            .....
        </util:map>
    </property>
```

Comment: Hey @minion! Thanks for responding.  Unfortunately the element 'key' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type 
is element-only.  So I'll still have to do something like this:



`<entry key="US" >
......
</entry>`

Comment: Also, in what way would I Instantiate the country? Like this you think?
`<property name="US" value="CountryCode.US" />`

Comment: Yeah. you will instantiate as you would do it as a regular spring bean. If you can instantiate as via property setter, you can do it. Another cleaner way might be to define those country code outside the map  and provide bean ref to those beans inside the value element. If you need further help, post your CreditCardManagementServiceStub.CountryCode. i can provide a sample. Please accept/upvote if it had helped.

Comment: Just wanted to find out if it helped?

Comment: Yes! Thank you.  This helped immensely.  Unfortunately I did not end up going that route as it was just easier to just create a static map elsewhere in the code at that point.  This implementation did work and help though, and will be in my back pocket for future projects.  Thanks!